# Jboss clustering: mod_cluster mod_cluster_proxy.so causing apache to crash

Tags: apache, jboss, jboss7.x, cluster-computing, mod-cluster

I am trying create a cluster of JBoss AS 7.1.1 (two instances in one machine with port offset as 100) in standalone mode. I am using apache (ver 2.2.22) with mod_cluster(ver 1.2.0) for load balancing. When I bring up both JBoss I could see the cluster view updated with both the nodes. But, I am getting the following error in Jboss:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.modcluster.mcmp.impl.DefaultMCMPHandler]  (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Error [MEM: MEM: Can't read  node: {4}] sending command STATUS to proxy 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:6666, configuration will be reset
```

In Apache logs, here is what I have:

```
[notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[notice] Advertise initialized for process 4924
[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) PHP/5.3.13 mod_cluster/1.2.0.Final configured --   resuming normal operations
[notice] Server built: May 13 2012 19:41:17
[notice] Parent: Created child process 2000
[notice] Child 2000: Child process is running
[notice] Child 2000: Acquired the start mutex.
[notice] Child 2000: Starting 64 worker threads.
[notice] Child 2000: Starting thread to listen on port 6666.
[notice] Child 2000: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[notice] Child 2000: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[warn] manager_handler STATUS error: MEM: Can't read node
```

It looks like apache is crashing due to faulty module mod_cluster_proxy.so module. I could figure it out from the windows event logs. Here is what I have in the event log:

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.2.22.0, time stamp: 0x4faff1ba
Faulting module name: mod_proxy.so, version: 2.2.21.0, time stamp: 0x4f3494b7
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000003115
Faulting process id: 0x12b4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf4735c4635dbb
```

Can anyone please help me out with how to solve this? Do I have to use a different version of mod_cluster? Is there any config changes I need to make? Here are my configs:

standalone-ha.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.0">
        <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" proxy-list="127.0.0.1:6666">
            <dynamic-load-provider>
                <load-metric type="busyness"/>
            </dynamic-load-provider>
        </mod-cluster-config>
</subsystem>
```

httpd.conf in apache:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:6666
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:6666>
<Directory />
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 127.0.0
</Directory>

KeepAliveTimeout 300
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0    
AdvertiseFrequency 5
ManagerBalancerName mycluster
EnableMCPMReceive

<Location /mod_cluster-manager>
   SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0
   AllowDisplay On
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Kindly let me know how to solve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is definitely not a configuration error. Please, try it out with [1.2.6](http://mod-cluster.jboss.org/downloads/1-2-6-Final-bin) and stay tuned for 1.2.9 and 1.3.x builds...

Edit: The latest and greatest build built for the community is [mod_cluster 1.3.1.Final](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ModclusterVersion131FinalReleased).